# Why are negative array indices much slower than positive array indices?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's a simple JavaScript performance test:

```js
const iterations = new Array(10 ** 7);

var x = 0;
var i = iterations.length + 1;
console.time('negative');
while (--i) {
 x += iterations[-i];
}
console.timeEnd('negative');

var y = 0;
var j = iterations.length;
console.time('positive');
while (j--) {
 y += iterations[j];
}
console.timeEnd('positive');
```

The first loop counts from 10,000,000 down to 1 and accesses an array with a length of 10 million using a negative index on each iteration. So it goes through the array from beginning to end.

The second loop counts from 9,999,999 down to 0 and accesses the same array using a positive index on each iteration. So it goes through the array in reverse.

On my PC, the first loop takes longer than 6 seconds to complete, but the second one only takes ~400ms.

Why is the second loop faster than the first?

Comment: I'm not even sure how the first one is working.  It looks like you are giving an array a negative index.

Comment: Negative array indices are the same as non-numeric string property names; they're not actually indexes into the array as an array, but property lookups into the array as an *object*. Each one of those will result in `undefined`, but the runtime has to perform a property name lookup. Array indexing, by contrast, can be heavily optimized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `iterations[-1]` will evaluate to `undefined` (which is slow as it has to go up the whole prototype chain and can't take a fast path) also doing math with `NaN` will always be slow as it is the non common case.

Also initializing `iterations` with numbers will make the whole test more useful.

Pro Tip: If you try to compare the performance of two codes, they should both result in the same operation at the end ...

---

Some general words about performance tests:

Performance is the compiler's job these days, code optimized by the compiler will always be faster than code you are trying to optimize through some "tricks". Therefore you should write code that is likely by the compiler to optimize, and that is in every case, the *code that everyone else* writes (also your coworkers will love you if you do so). Optimizing that is the most benefitial from the engine's view. Therefore I'd write:

```
 let acc = 0;
 for(const value of array) acc += value;

 // or
 const acc = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

However in the end *it's just a loop*, you won't waste much time if the loop is performing bad, but you will if the whole algorithm performs bad (time complexity of O(n²) or more). Focus on the important things, not the loops.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Jonas Wilms' answer, Javascript does not work with negative indice (unlike languages like Python).

`iterations[-1]` is equal to `iteration["-1"]`, which look for the property named -1 in the array object. That's why `iterations[-1]` will evaluate to `undefined`.